# What is the best way to connect external monitors to mid-2014 Macbook Pro Retina so you can get the best resolution?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, resolution

I have a mid-2014 15" Macbook Pro Retina.   I've got a bunch of plugs (HDMI, 2 mini DP) and my external 27" ACER K272HUL has HDML, DP and DVI.   My assumption is that there are differences between the plugs (support of different resolutions).   What is the best way to connect external monitors to mid-2014 Macbook Pro Retina so you can get the best resolution?

Comment: miniDP -> DP works best for me

Comment: So they don't have that adapter at the apple store.  which one did you get?

Comment: probably StarTech, they're my usual source - they sell direct + have dealers round the world. Just google "startech mini displayport to display port" or leave out startech & see who's got one cheaper